# Changing position after setting position of character

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

hi my character is stacking in the same position even if i move my character forward and backward here is my code so far, hope you'll help me the code below for the setting of character position is from the Load area where the x,y,z position is from the position where the character is saved

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainCharacterMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public  Animator anim;
    public GameObject main;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        anim.SetFloat ("Directions",0);
        Vector3 tempx = main.transform.position;
        tempx.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("x"); 
        main.transform.position = tempx;
        Vector3 tempy = main.transform.position;
        tempx.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("y"); 
        main.transform.position = tempx;
        Vector3 tempz = main.transform.position;
        tempx.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("z"); 
        main.transform.position = tempx;



            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
           {

            anim.SetFloat("Directions",1);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*2*Time.deltaTime);

            }


            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {

            anim.SetFloat("Directions",2);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right*2*Time.deltaTime);
        }


        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {

            anim.SetFloat("Directions",3);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left*2*Time.deltaTime);
        }



        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {

            anim.SetFloat("Directions",4);
            //transform.Translate(Vector3.left*2*Time.deltaTime);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the animation is stuck or that the character isn't moving from his original location?

Comment: Does your character stay stuck in the same position only when you move in certain directions, or it stays stuck regardless of which direction you try to move?

Comment: You realize that you're picking up "temp.x", "temp.y" from PlayerPrefs EVERY frame? This means that you're essentially sticking you character back to it's original position EVERY FRAME!. Further, I don't see you overwriting that value either

Comment: Was about to post an answer mentioning that, @VenkatatAxiomStudios. Might as well do it now, since it's the only thing I can see wrong at the moment. =P

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is with every `Update()` loop, you are resetting your `main.transform.position` to something partially set from your `PlayerPrefs` - meaning even if you change that particular value in response to a keypress, by the next frame it will jump back to its initial value. I'd advise moving this code to `Start()`, since that would be the correct place to initialize a position in this case.

Your logic for loading the player position from memory seems to be a bit erroneous as well - although you declare and initialize `Vector3 tempy` and `Vector3 tempz`, you never actually use them. Rather, you overwrite your x-value repeatedly with your x, y, and z values. (So I expect it is only the x-value of the position that gets reset each frame.)

So, taking the position-loading code out of your `Update()` loop and into `Start()`, then fixing the logic:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    Vector3 tempPosition = new Vector3();
    tempPosition.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("x"); 
    tempPosition.y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("y"); 
    tempPosition.z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("z"); 
    main.transform.position = tempPosition;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong going on here i dont know where to start.

First of all `Vector3 Tempx` `Vector3 Tempy` `Vector3 Tempz`? You only need a single `Vector3 temp` which will contain all `x` `y` and `z`.

```
Vector3 tempx = main.transform.position;
tempx.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("x"); 
main.transform.position = tempx;
Vector3 tempy = main.transform.position;  // Why new var? This is not needed.
tempx.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("y");     // Tempx.x again... did you mean Tempx.y?
main.transform.position = tempx;
Vector3 tempz = main.transform.position;  // Why new var? This is not needed.
tempx.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("z");     // Tempx.x again... did you mean Tempx.z?
main.transform.position = tempx;
```

not to mention 3 calls to `main.transform.position = tempx;` in a row

I think this is what you meant:

```
Vector3 temp = new Vector3(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("x"),
    PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("y"),
    PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("z"));

main.transform.position = temp;

// or
main.transform.position += temp;

// or
main.transform.position += temp * Time.deltaTime;
```